# Find the value of $x^2 + y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Where
$$x = \frac{\sqrt3 + 1}{\sqrt3 - 1}$$
$$y = \frac{\sqrt3 - 1}{\sqrt3 + 1}$$

Bonus: prove (x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 +2xy

Comment: Using trigonometry, $x = -\cot 15$ and $y= \tan 15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

So, $xy=1$

and $\displaystyle x=\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3-1}=\frac{(\sqrt3+1)^2}{(\sqrt3-1)(\sqrt3+1)}=2+\sqrt3$

$\displaystyle y=?$

Finally, $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+y^2= (x+y)^2-2xy$­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­